# Delegation to another object of same type using by does not even compile

Tags: kotlin, delegates, delegation

I am trying to understand how the delegate keyword `by` works.
So delegating to implemenent an interface is clear e.g.

```
class Manager(clientele: List<Client> = ArrayList()): List<Client> by clientale
```

But the following does not work:

```
data class Client(val name: String, val postalCode: Int)  
fun createClient() = Client("Bob", 1234)
val bigClient: Client by createClient() // compilation error
```

I get the error:

> Missing getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>) method delegate of type
>   Client

I thought that if two objects are the same the delegation from one to the other (Client by Client) would work.
Can someone please explain what is the error here and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not exactly how delegation of properties works. Based on the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#property-delegate-requirements):

> For a read-only property (i.e. a `val`), a delegate has to provide a function named `getValue` that takes the following parameters:
>
> - `thisRef` - must be the same or a supertype of the property owner;
> - `property` - must be of type `KProperty<*>` or its supertype.
>
> For a mutable property (a `var`), a delegate has to additionally provide a function named `setValue` that takes the following parameters:
>
> - `thisRef` - same as for `getValue()`;
> - `property` - same as for `getValue()`;
> - `newValue` - must be of the same type as the property or its subtype.
>
> [...] Both of the functions need to be marked with the operator keyword.

So in order just to make your example work, you have to add a `getValue()` method which meets the above requirements:

```
data class Client(val name: String, val postalCode: Int) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Nothing?, property: KProperty<*>): Client = this
}
```

You can also use and implement the `ReadOnlyProperty` and `ReadWriteProperty` interfaces which provide the required methods:

```
data class Client(val name: String, val postalCode: Int) : ReadOnlyProperty<Nothing?, Client> {
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Nothing?, property: KProperty<*>): Client = this
}
```

---

### Edit:

> What is this `getValue()` supposed to do?

Let me explain a little further on a more abstract example. We have the following classes:

```
class MyDelegate : ReadWriteProperty<MyClass, String> {

    private var delegateProperty: String = ""

    override fun getValue(thisRef: MyClass, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        println("$thisRef delegated getting the ${property.name}'s value to $this")
        return delegateProperty
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: MyClass, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        println("$thisRef delegated setting the ${property.name}'s value to $this, new value: $value")
        delegateProperty = value
    }
}

class MyClass {
    var property: String by MyDelegate()
}
```

The above `MyClass` would get compiled more or less to:

```
class MyClass {
    private var property$delegate: MyDelegate = MyDelegate()

    var property: String
        get() = property$delegate.getValue(this, this::property)
        set(value) = property$delegate.setValue(this, this::property, value)
}
```

So you can see that the compiler requires a delegate to have `getValue()` and `setValue()` methods for mutable properties (`var`) or only `getValue()` for immutable properites (`val`), because it uses them to respectively get and set the delegated property's value.

---

> What are Nothing and KProperty<*>?

[`KProperty<*>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property/index.html) is a Kotlin class which represents a property and provides its metadata.

[`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html) is a type that represents a value that doesn't exist. It's quite irrelevant from the delegation point of view. It came up in this case, because you probably defined the `bigClient` property outside any class so it has no owner, hence `thisRef` is `Nothing`.

Comment: But that does this `getValue`? supposed to do? Could you please elaborate a bit on the syntax? I don't know what is `Nothing` and `KProperty<*>`

Comment: @Jim I've updated my answer. I hope it answers your questions now.

Comment: I copied your example and 1) I don't know what to do inside the implementation of `getValue()/setValue()`. Where is the value retrieved from? 2) It does not compile. Specifically this line `private var property: String by MyDelegate = MyDelegate()` complaints that `Assignments are not expressions and only expressions are allowed in this context`

Comment: @Jim I've edited my answer and provided an example implementation of `getValue()` and `setValue()`. Basically what you want to do is provide the value you want to get when you call `property` and handle the new value when calling `property = "other string"`.  And please, check if you copied my example correctly, I wrote `private var property: String by MyDelegate()` not `... by MyDelegate = MyDelegate()`.

Comment: You are right I had a typo. But in your example `MyClass` has `private var property`. So I can't call neither a getter not a setter. So how can I use this class? I see that if I remove the `private` the methods are indeed called. Is the `private` for a reason?

Comment: @Jim No, the `private` modifier isn't necessary and can be omitted. My bad, I should have removed it when you signalized you'd tried to run the example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!